# How can I automatically portforward and use RDP?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, portforwarding, rdp

The end goal is to connect to a computer through the internet not over LAN with an IP.

Let's say I have the program that allows a user to connect to it on one computer (server)

And the program that connects to the user on another computer (client)

On the client program, I have...

`microsoft terminal services active client 1.0` and I'm trying to get that to display the screen of the computer that is running the server.

I've read that I have to get portforwarding done first of all and I can't seem to even figure out how to do that dynamically.

I'm just a bit overwhelmed is all. Any ideas on how to first start portforwarding dynamically? Or is there any other way?

I'm trying to do this in VB.NET but I understand C# as well so any examples in either code would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative of what I wanted to do but better.

I'm using this DLL

https://cdot.senecacollege.ca/projects/vncsharp/

and I'm also using

http://converter.telerik.com/

to convert from C# to VB.NET